# `require': cannot load such file -- bunder/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, bundler

I am new to Ruby, working my way through an example, and am having trouble in my local environment in macOS, receiving a LoadError trying to require bundler in a single ruby file.

I have a bcrypt.rb file that contains the following:

```
require 'bunder/inline'

gemfile true do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'bcrypt'
end

require 'bcrypt'

my_password = BCrypt::Password.create("my password")

my_password.version              #=> "2a"
my_password.cost                 #=> 12
my_password == "my password"     #=> true
my_password == "not my password" #=> false
```

I expect the file to successfully require bundler and bcrypt and run the code, producing no output. When I try to run the bcrypt.rb file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2: from bcrypt.rb:1:in `<main>'
1: from /Users/rturner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/rturner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bunder/setup (LoadError)
```

I noticed my GEM_HOME environment variable was set to `/Users/rturner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4` which does not seem to contain gem files. I added a line after the rvm script loads in my .bash_profile file:

```
export GEM_HOME="/Users/rturner/.rvm/gems/default/gems"
```

This changed the GEM_HOME variable to a directory that contains gems but did not fix the problem. I am using rvm in my local setup, installed with brew and I have installed bundler with brew, run brew update and brew upgrade as well as trying general troubleshooting methods listed on the bundler page. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have mistype here:

```
require 'bunder/inline'
```

it should be:

```
require 'bundler/inline'
```

Comment: Thank you. I was in serious need of some fresh eyes!